# Randomly select elements from a big text file

Tags: java, file, random

I have a big file which has 30 Million User ID's. That big file will look something like this and each line will have an User Id.

```
149905320
1165665384
66969324
886633368
1145241312
286585320
1008665352
1135545396
186217320
132577356
```

Now, I am planning to get any random line from that big text file. I know the total number of user id's in that big text file. I am not sure what is the best way to select random elements from that big text file. I was thinking to store all those 30Million user ids in a set and then randomly select elements from the hastset but with this approach it will go with out of memory error.

So that is the reason, I am trying to randomly select elements from  a big text file.

```
final String id = generateRandomUserId(random);

/**
 * Select random elements from the a big text file
 * 
 * @param userIdsSet2
 * @param r
 * @return
 */
private String generateRandomUserId(Random r) {

     File bigFile = new File("C:\\bigfile.txt");

     //randomly select elements from a big text file         


}
```

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you store the user ids as fixed width by padding them with spaces or something. Then you can calculate the offset of an entry and seek straight to it.

Comment: @gordy: The real question is: Why doesn't he create a database? If your project is so huge that you have 3e10 user id's, then storing them in a text file looks bad to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do like so :

- Get the size of the file (in bytes)
- Pick a byte (randomly chosen number in [0..file.length()] - `RandomAccessFile`)
- Seek to that position in the file (`file.seek(number)`)
- Seek to the position right after the next `\n` character (`file.seek(1)`)
- Read line (`file.readLine()`)

for example...

This way you don't have to store anything.

A sample theoretic snippet could look like this (contains some side effects) :

```
File f = new File("D:/abc.txt");
RandomAccessFile file;
try {
    file = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
    long file_size = file.length();
    long chosen_byte = (long)(Math.random() * file_size);

    file.seek(chosen_byte);

    for (;;)
    {
        byte a_byte = file.readByte();
        char wordChar = (char)a_byte;
        if (chosen_byte >= file_size || wordChar == '\n' || wordChar == '\r' || wordChar == -1) break;
        else chosen_byte += 1;
        System.out.println("\"" + Character.toString(wordChar)  + "\"");
    }

    int chosen = -1;
    if (chosen_byte < file_size) 
    {
        String s = file.readLine();
        chosen = Integer.parseInt(s);
        System.out.println("Chosen id : \"" + s  + "\"");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** ***Full working (theoretically) class***

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;


public class Main {

    /**
     * WARNING : This piece of code requires that the input file terminates by a BLANK line !
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File f = new File("D:/abc.txt");
        RandomAccessFile file;

        try {

            file = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
            long file_size = file.length();

            // Let's start
            long chosen_byte = (long)(Math.random() * (file_size - 1));
            long cur_byte = chosen_byte;

            // Goto starting position
            file.seek(cur_byte);

            String s_LR = "";
            char a_char;

            // Get left hand chars
            for (;;)
            {
                a_char = (char)file.readByte();
                if (cur_byte < 0 || a_char == '\n' || a_char == '\r' || a_char == -1) break;
                else 
                {
                    s_LR = a_char + s_LR;
                    --cur_byte;
                    if (cur_byte >= 0) file.seek(cur_byte);
                    else break;
                }
            }

            // Get right hand chars
            cur_byte = chosen_byte + 1;
            file.seek(cur_byte);
            for (;;)
            {
                a_char = (char)file.readByte();
                if (cur_byte >= file_size || a_char == '\n' || a_char == '\r' || a_char == -1) break;
                else 
                {
                    s_LR += a_char;
                    ++cur_byte;
                }
            }

            // Parse ID
            if (cur_byte < file_size) 
            {
                int chosen_id = Integer.parseInt(s_LR);
                System.out.println("Chosen id : " + chosen_id);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Ran out of bounds. But this usually never happen...");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this is not too wrong as an implementation (I'm more C++ those days)...

Comment: +1. To achieve this, you will need to use RandomAccessFile. Take a look at it by Googl'ing it.

Comment: @Golgauth, Can you provide any simpe example by which I will be able to understand better.?

Comment: this is a smart solution. you can also just read a block of 30 bytes from some random place in the file and parse between the two \n's

Comment: intValue method at the end is having compilation issues. I am getting as `The method intValue() in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Comment: Yeah I'm java rusty : that was `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: Yeah that fine. One more issue at- `char a_byte = file.readByte()` as I am getting- Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte to char

Comment: @gordy Right, this would be more secure this way (ensuring not to run beyond EOF).

Comment: There is a problem that longer lines are more likely to be chosen

Comment: @PeterLawrey Good thinking : the algorithm will not be very uniform. Ideally we would use ids of same size in the file (prefixed by zeros for the shortest ones : 0002565642) and use for example a [Mersenne Twister RNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister).

Comment: It is giving me EOFException with your change.

Comment: Ok, give me a minute... opening eclipse... :)

Comment: Got it. Updated. But keep in mind `gordy`'s remark. The algorithm I give will never return the very first id and will crash on the very last. I'm trying to fix it...

Comment: DONE! -- One more thing - about Random Number Generator : Java implementations of the Mersenne Twister algorithm can be found [here](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/JAVA/java.html). In case the uniformity of the distribution of the generated numbers matters in what you're implementing.

Comment: Golgauth, The default Java `Random` class suffices for this task (and also yields a uniform distribution). No need to bring MT-19937 into this. We're not talking about Monte Carlo simulations or multidimensional values here.

Comment: Yes, you're certainly right. But as my main concerns at work currently are precisely simulations, it's been reflex :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the user ids in a hash you could parse the file and store just the offsets in an int[] array - 30M would take ~120MB of RAM.

Alternatively if you can change or preprocess the file in some way you could change the format to fixed width by padding the user ids or use a binary format.

Comment: Or just parse the file and store the user IDs in an int array.

Comment: @Joey doh! yeah that seems obvious now

Answer (score 0):

The OP states: "I know the total number of user id's in that big text file". Call this N.

- Generate a random number between 1 and N inclusive.
- Read lines (BufferedReader) until you reach the Nth line.
- Done